# Enable token caching after validation through the OAuth.io javascript SDK

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I'm creating a website (in AngularJS) which uses the Google Analytics API through [OAuth.io](http://www.oauth.io)'s javascript SDK.

Everything was quite simple to set up, however their [documentation](https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/client/javascript) is really lacking; it's very short, with little code examples.

Currently everytime I refresh my page I need to validate again (through the pop-up), and saw there was a way to enable caching using their SDK (*note: I know it can be done with cookies or browser storage, but I would like to use their SDK to do it.*)

It's explained here: https://oauth.io/docs/api-reference/client/javascript#detailed-description-oauth-object-available-methods-popup

You can use 'options, enable cache', but I really have no idea how and where to add this argument to do so.

---

My code for the pop-up:

```
$scope.connect.analytics = function() {
    OAuth.popup('google_analytics')
        .done(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.connect.status = true;
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it using `{cache: true}` as second parameter:

```
$scope.connect.analytics = function() {
    OAuth.popup('google_analytics', {cache: true})
        .done(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            $scope.connect.status = true;
        })
        .fail(function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        });
};
```

The second time the popup is called, it won't display the popup and go directly in the callback with the previous response.

You can use after `OAuth.clearCache('google_analytics');` to clear the cache of a specific provider.